# ASP.Net MVC & jQuery Form Plugin Uploading a File

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

Can someone give me an example of how to do this with ASP.Net MVC? I have followed the example at their [site](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#code-samples) on the file uploads tab but I cannot get a decent response back. My controller thinks that it is not a AJAXRequest and tries to do a RedirectToAction but that doesn't change the page after the post.

Answer (score 14):

I wrote a blog post about how to do this [here](http://aspzone.com/tech/jquery-file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-without-using-flash/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this my friend: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx

Comment: That doesn't use the jQuery Form Plugin

Comment: Perhaps you would prefer this post then!  http://forums.asp.net/p/1298139/2527969.aspx#2527969

Answer (score 0):

The upload isn't an AJAX request, it states clearly that you can't do a file upload using the XMLHttpRequest object so it's done using an iframe as the target. Try processing the upload just as you would for a normal non-AJAX submission.

Comment: I do, I check the Request.IsAJAXRequest property and then do a RedirectToAction("Index") but I don't get redirected to Index it just comes back to my form page.

Answer (score -6):

Answer: Cannot use AJAX or use iFrame